# Lightbox2 navigation images missing when using importmap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, lightbox2, import-maps

In a rails 7.1 project I'm using importmap to load lightbox2

```
importmap.rb
pin "lightbox2", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:lightbox2@2.11.4/dist/js/lightbox.js"
```

This works but none of the navigation images are being loaded. Such as the X < > overlayed onto the image when enlarged.
The html is referencing them as `lightbox2/close.png` - I've cloned the lightbox2 gem and manually copied the images into the `app/assets/images/lightbox2` directory but this doesn't feel like the correct solution as it doesn't work - the url needs `assets` prefixing to it.

How should I include the Lightbox2 navigation images in a rails 7.1 project?

Answer (score 0):

Putting this here for any other poor soul that has this issue:

I had to download the css (.scss) from the Lightbox url and add it into the `app/stylesheets/vendors` directory. Before it can work though the image names within it need to have a prefix of `assets/` adding and the `image_path` command removing.

So

`background: url(image_path('lightbox2/close.png')) top right no-repeat;`

becomes

`background: url('assets/lightbox2/close.png') top right no-repeat;`

Once done rebuild the application css file and the images appeared.